# Eclipse jboss tools: can't instantiate jacorb or sun ORB in WildFly

Tags: wildfly, jacorb

Using Eclipse with Jboss Tools. I can create a WildFly 8.0 Runtime all right but it does not include jacorb automatically. WildFly comes with org.jboss.as.jacorb module in /system/base/org/jacorb. I added the following to standalone.xml:

```
<extensions>  
    ...  
    ...  
   <extension module="org.jacorb"/>  
</extension>
```

That module contains a dependency to module "org.jacorb" which contains the actual ORB implementation.
However, I get a class not found error when trying to instantiate the ORB. The ORB class, contained in the module org.jacorb, is not being found:

```
 15:03:43,021 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4) java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jacorb.orb.ORB from [Module "deployment.SM_Web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
 15:03:43,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
 15:03:43,131 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:459)
 15:03:43,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:408)
 15:03:43,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:389)
 15:03:43,132 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:134)
 15:03:43,172 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 15:03:43,172 ERROR [stderr] (default task-4)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
```

When I set: "org.omg.CORBA.ORBClass" property to "com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl"
I get:
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.corba.se.impl.orb.ORBImpl from [Module "deployment.SM_Web.war:main" from Service Module Loader]

Do I have to do something special to instantiate an ORB in WildFly?

Update: got it to work. I was on the right track, what was missing was the following jboss-deployment-structure.xml under WEB-INF:

Add the following jboss-deployment-structure.xml under WEB-INF:

```
 <jboss-deployment-structure>  
  <deployment>  
    <dependencies>  
     <module name="org.jacorb" />  
    </dependencies>  
  </deployment>  
 </jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work, per updated question at the bottom. I was missing jboss-deployment-structure.xml.